# Pandas convert <NA> to NaN while keeping other values as integer

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am currently trying to convert a pandas dataframe column of float values with nan to int values while retaining the nan values. However, I am facing issues where if I try to do df.astype("Int64") on the column with float values, it converts the nan with  which is the pd.NA form of nan (if I am not wrong).

For example, I am trying to convert the example 1 into example 2 format:

```
example 1:
weights
100.0
100.0
100.0
NaN
NaN
NaN
100.0
```

to

```
example 2:
weights
100
100
100
NaN
NaN
NaN
100
```

but I am getting the results below:

```
weights
100
100
100
<NA>
<NA>
<NA>
100
```

I understand that I get  because I am forcing the conversion using "I"nt64 as I can't convert the nan using int64 but when I try to convert the  using df.replace({pd.NA : np.nan}) I get back float type data for the non-NaN values as well just like example 1.

I tried splitting the data into non-NaN values by using df.loc[~df["weights"].isna(), "weights"] and converting them to int values separately then join back, but it keeps converting itself back to float type.

Is it possible to get values like example 2 where integer values and nan exist together?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible to mix `int` with `NaN`. That was the reason pandas created `Int64` and `<NA>`.

Comment: It's "possible" if you make it a generic `object` column.

Comment: You cannot have an integer array with NaN because NaN is a float.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I guess I have to work with NA and change them to string or something!